Graphic.py Making a ball go through a certain path
Hello I have a school project were i need a ball to go through the entire area of the window however there are obstacles in between and it has to return 2 base. My line of thought was to go always on the vertical and everytime it hits an obstacle or the end of the widow it goes horizontal the size of it radius and then goes back down.
However i Havent been able to find the best commands to do that, so was just using "if" conditions.
If anyone has any tip on how to procede or even a different method
Code
